# How to get rid of overlaying

Tags: html, css, sass

The main problem is that the header is fixed and thus overlaying the main part of the web page.

So, what I did is just margin-top to the main part, which appears to be not working.

Moreover, if you delete the header, the main section just goes too up.

Overview:

[image]

Without header :
[image: without header]

### HTML:

```
<header class="header">
    <nav class="navbar">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="index.html">Visualizer</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item"><a class="nav-link" href="instruction.html">Instructions</a></li>
            <li class="nav-item active"><a class="nav-link" href="credits.html">Credits</a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
</header>

<main class="credits">
    <div class="">

        <div class="cr-card">
            <div class="cr-img">
                <img src="img/p1.png">
            </div>

            <div class="cr-info">

                <h1 class="cr-name">
                    Lorem
                </h1>
                <p class="cr-about">
                    lorem ipsum
                </p>
                <ul class="cr-links">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://github.com/lorem"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://t.me/lorem"><i class="fab fa-telegram"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/lorem/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cr-card">
            <div class="cr-img">
                <img src="img/p1.png">
            </div>

            <div class="cr-info">

                <h1 class="cr-name">
                    Lorem
                </h1>
                <p class="cr-about">
                    lorem ipsum
                </p>
                <ul class="cr-links">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://github.com/lorem"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://t.me/lorem"><i class="fab fa-telegram"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/lorem/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="cr-card">
            <div class="cr-img">
                <img src="img/p1.png">
            </div>

            <div class="cr-info">

                <h1 class="cr-name">
                    Lorem
                </h1>
                <p class="cr-about">
                    lorem ipsum
                </p>
                <ul class="cr-links">
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://github.com/lorem"><i class="fab fa-github"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://t.me/lorem"><i class="fab fa-telegram"></i></a>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <a href="https://www.instagram.com/lorem/"><i class="fab fa-instagram"></i></a>
                    </li>
                </ul>

            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</main>
```

### SCSS HEADER:

```
.header {
    margin-top: 0px;
    top: 0;
    width: 100%;
    height: $header-height;
    z-index: 5;
    background: radial-gradient(at center top, rgb(46, 51, 58) 0, rgba(27, 30, 34, 0) 80%);
    border: 1px;

    .navbar {
        width: 100%;
        margin-right: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        display: flex;
        flex-flow: row nowrap;
        justify-content: center;
        align-items: center;

        .navbar-nav {
            display: flex;
            flex-flow: row nowrap;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;

            .nav-item {
                display: flex;
                align-items: center;
                justify-content: center;
                color: #ffffff;
                cursor: pointer;

                .nav-link {
                    font-family: "Raleway", "Hack", Arial, sans-serif;
                    font-size: 1.1em;
                    color: white;
                    height: 68px;
                    line-height: 68px;
                    padding: 0 15px;
                    border-bottom: 0px #3d5cff solid;

                    &:hover {
                        border-bottom: 5px #3d5cff solid;
                    }
                }

                &.active {
                    .nav-link {
                        border-bottom: 5px #fff solid;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

### MAIN PART:

```
.credits {
    > div {
        display: flex;
        flex-direction: row;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        justify-content: space-evenly;
        align-items: center;
        align-content: center;

        .cr-card {
            color: #dad8f5;
            font-family: Optima, Arial, sans-serif;
            width: 40%;

            .cr-img {
                img {
                    display: block;
                    width: 60%;

                    /* border: 1vw solid #343A40   */
                    border: 1vw solid rgb(38, 43, 48);
                    box-shadow: 0 10px 30px rgb(38, 43, 48);
                    border-radius: 50%;
                    margin: auto;
                }
            }

            .cr-info {
                margin-top: -30%;
                background-color: #343a40;
                border-radius: 5px;
                padding: 33% 1.5rem 0;
                font-size: 1.3vw;

                .cr-name {
                    font-weight: 400;
                    font-size: 2.6vw;
                    text-align: center;
                    background-color: #343a40;
                    border-bottom: 2px solid rgb(38, 43, 48);
                    border-bottom-left-radius: 5px;
                    border-bottom-right-radius: 5px;
                    box-shadow: 0 6px 10px -11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);
                }

                .cr-about {
                    text-align: center;
                }

                .cr-links {
                    display: flex;
                    flex-direction: row;
                    justify-content: space-evenly;
                    border-top: 2px solid rgb(38, 43, 48);
                    border-top-left-radius: 5px;
                    border-top-right-radius: 5px;
                    box-shadow: 0 -6px 10px -11px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.75);

                    li {
                        padding: 1.3vw 0;

                        a {
                            font-size: 6vw;
                            color: #dad8f5;

                            i {
                                &:hover {
                                    text-shadow: 0px 0px 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us the CSS for your MAIN tag? Also might be helpful to put your code into a JSFIDDLE

Comment: oops. forgot about it, just a sec

Comment: I don't see where you margin-top the .credits MAIN tag... Are you sure you are putting a margin top on it?